# query make a count to 1 which does not satistfy the condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

i have a two table i want to know the number of person who are all assigned to project in each sector

```
CREATE TABLE first1( a int,projectname varchar(20));
INSERT INTO first1 VALUES
(1001,'crm'),
(1002,'iic'),
(1003,'abc'),
(1004,'sifty bank');

CREATE TABLE diff(b int,name varchar(20),p_id int );
INSERT INTO diff VALUES
(101,'priya',1001),
(102,'divya',1002),
(103,'sidhu',null),
(104,'shiva',null),
(105,'surya',1002);
```

Query:

```
select first1.projectname,count(*) from first1  left join diff on first1.a=diff.p_id group by 
first1.projectname;
```

The output of this code is:

```
abc|1
crm|1
iic|2
sifty bank|1
```

The expected output is :

```
abc|0
crm|1
iic|2
sifty bank|0
```

Comment: I'm lost.  What is a "sector"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `count(*)`; it counts how many rows there are in each group - A project without any person assigned still counts as 1. Instead, you need to `count()` something from the left table, so `null` values are not taken into account:

```
select f.projectname, count(d.p_id) as cnt_diff
from first1 f
left join diff d on f.a = d.p_id 
group by f.projectname;
```

Note that you can get the same result with a subquery:

```
select f.projectname, 
    (select count(*) from diff d where d.p_id = f.a)  as cnt_diff
from first1 f
```